# SwiftyJson parse oData response

Tags: swift, odata, swifty-json

I am trying to parse a oData web service using SwiftyJSON

Here is my oData response:

```
{
  "odata.metadata":"http://url.com/odata/$metadata#Updates","value":[
    {
      "ID":1,"msgTitle":"Testing","reportedBy":"testUser"
    }

  ]
}
```

Here is my Swift code:

```
 Alamofire.request(URL, method: .get).responseString { (responseData) -> Void in
            if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
                print(swiftyJsonVar)
                if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["value"].arrayObject {
                    if let dict = resData as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
                        for obj in dict {
                            let announce = announcement(fileDict: obj)
                            self.Announcements.append(announce)
                        }

                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        self.tableView.isHidden = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is that resData is returning null.  What I am doing wrong to get the JSON within the value array?

I have also tried swiftyJsonVar[0]["value"].arrayObject without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting the swiftyJSON documentation, I was able to figure this out using the following syntax:

```
Alamofire.request(URL, method: .get).responseString { (responseData) -> Void in
            if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                //log.info("Response: \(responseData.result.value)")
                let jsonObj = responseData.result.value!
                if let dataFromString = jsonObj.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) {
                    let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)
                    print(json)
                    if let resData = json["value"].arrayObject {
                        if let dict = resData as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
                            for obj in dict {
                                let announce = announcement(fileDict: obj)
                                self.Announcements.append(announce)
                            }

                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                            self.tableView.isHidden = false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```